# pyautogui slight delay in key presses

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

So I want to hold down the c key for lets say 0.2 seconds and release it. To do that I thought using pyautogui.keyDown("")
and keyUp("") would help but it has a slight delay in it so like when I do

```
pyautogui.keyDown("c")
time.sleep(0.2)
pyautogui.keyUp("C")
```

What it does is holds the key "c" for longer than 0.2 seconds, I just want it to press c for 0.2 seconds. My main code is:

```
import pyautogui
import time
time.sleep(0.5)

pyautogui.keyDown("c")
time.sleep(0.2)
pyautogui.keyUp("c")
time.sleep(0.5)
pyautogui.keyDown("space")
pyautogui.keyUp("space")
time.sleep(0.5)
pyautogui.keyDown("c")
time.sleep(0.2)
pyautogui.keyUp("c")
time.sleep(0.5)
pyautogui.keyDown("space")
pyautogui.keyUp("space")
```

The time.sleep is the delay I want it to be but it has a delay on its own without the time.sleep.

EDIT: Solution was to disable failsafe

Comment: First of all, I would assign the keys you are using to variables, so you won't have an issue like lowercase c and uppercase C in your first example.  use the variable in all positions.   Also the timing in your program doesn't match the timing in your description, as far as I can see.  I will answer with a program which seems to match your description.

Comment: There is .1 second delay between commands for failsafe ability.  Documented here: [fail-safe](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#fail-safes).  It can be disabled, but that is not recommended or you might not be able to regain control of your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the documentation and apparently there is a .1 second delay between `pyautogui` commands, to allow you to break into the operation manually in case of runaway, documented here: [#fail-safe](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#fail-safes).  They warn against it, but you might be able to do this:

```
import pyautogui
import time

KEY_C = "c"
KEY_SPACE = "space"

time.sleep(0.5)

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False # danger zone
pyautogui.keyDown(KEY_C)
time.sleep(0.2)
pyautogui.keyUp(KEY_C)
pyautogui.keyDown(KEY_SPACE)
pyautogui.keyUp(KEY_SPACE)
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True # out of danger

# do it again

time.sleep(0.5)
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
pyautogui.keyDown(KEY_C)
time.sleep(0.2)
pyautogui.keyUp(KEY_C)
pyautogui.keyDown(KEY_SPACE)
pyautogui.keyUp(KEY_SPACE)
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
```